# BX Slider is cutting the bottom off divs

Tags: css, bxslider

I'm using bx slider to show posts. When the page loads, part of the div is cut off, but if I resize the window it pops open. Have you seen anything like this? What could be cause?

Here's the live site: http://fatesallow.com/ It's the 3 posts under "Design."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently had the same issue like that, sometimes the slider won't even show up after reloading the page. Adding the following code into the CSS solved the issue.

```
.bx-viewport {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

*(it depends on the version of bxslider, and your actual markup, it may not work in all cases.)*